# Why don't we mention صلوٰة الشفع and صلوٰة الوتر as opposed to mentioning "Witr" only in our discussion of witr prayers?

Tags: salat

When praying 3 rakat witr: I was thought from childhood to say i intend to pray "salat shafa-e" for the 1st 2 even numbered rakats and then "witr" for the odd or 3rd rakat. but in our online discussion i don't see any mention of shafa-e when discussing witr prayers. what's the reason? Quran [89:3] mentioned وَالشَّفْعِ وَالْوَتْرِ.

Comment: Haven't searched anything yet. But the reason might be because you can pray as many shafa-es (evens) as you want. They can be 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 (don't know if they can be more) while Witr is only just one.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning salat *shafae*, it is a name of all salat you pray after the last prayer of a day ( *ichaa*) beginning by 2 rakaat to 8 or 10 for maximun and *shafae* in arabic means pair (2 rakaat) so in this salat every 2 *rakaat* must be preced by *tachahoud* and *taslim*.

After the salat of *shafae* you must pray the witr salat which mean in arabic odd it can be 1 rakaat or 3 rakaat without *tachahoud* in middle or 5 or even 7 and the prophet PBUH have prayed it in 4 kinds I've told you.

So the 3 rakaat you are praying if you do *tachahoud* and *tasslime* in the middle it is shafae(2)+witr(1) but if you don't do that it is only witr(3).